# PayPal Pro In Craft Commerce

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce, craft-pro, payment-methods

I am trying to integrate PayPal Pro into Craft Commerce, I have my API details added to the payment gateway and I have disabled test mode. I know these keys work as they have been used before.

On checkout, when I have PayPal Pro selected as a payment method, I receive an error "Invalid payment or order. Please review." when I press checkout.

I have two questions;

1. Could anyone give me an idea as to why this payment gateway isn't
   working but the other payment gateways are working fine? Maybe I'm making a common mistake somewhere.
2. Are there any ways of dumping out errors, the flash errors don't seem to provide any detail which is making debugging this issue difficult.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking at `commerce.log` in `storage/logs`? (With Craft 3/Commerce 2 there is no commerce.log - you'll need to comb through the general `web.log`)